# Does anyone know how to stop Windows notifications from a single specific website?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, notifications

Does anyone know how to stop notifications from a single specific website? In Chrome and/or Firefox? Obviously I know how to turn them off for the entire application.

But I went to this website to lookup an old girlfriend, like one those records report. Decided not to pay and go through with it. And for a week now it gives me a notification with her name and hey let’s finish this. And there is no where for me to click to close it without it opening the website page. And I have to continue clicking it till it goes away. Only to return every hour. Super Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

For [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox):

1. Click the padlock Gray padlock in the address bar.
2. Click the arrow in the Site Information drop-down panel.
3. Click More information in the next panel to bring up the Page Info window.
4. Click the Permissions tab.
5. Under Send Notifications, choose a notification option: Always Ask, Allow, or Block. If your choices are grayed out, deselect the Use Default checkbox.

For [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?visit_id=637139236847650061-3603443369&rd=1):

1. On your computer, open Chrome .
2. Go to a website.
3. To the left of the web address, click the icon you see: Lock Lock, Info View site information, or Dangerous Dangerous.
4. Click Site settings.
5. Change a permission setting. Your changes will automatically save.

Comment: Wow!!! Thank You SOOO MUCH!!!!